# In Javafx when a window is opened how can i set it so that the user isnt able to open the same window again?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I tried a lot but just couldn't find any solution. At the moment the opened window(popup window) is always on top but the user can still access the main window. That's how it should be, but it shouldn't be possible to open the same popup window again.

```
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle(panelTitle);     
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); 
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.showAndWait();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe disable the button which opens a window? and enable it when the window is closed? or maybe instead of creating a new one, just show it and hide it?

Comment: Using a singleton like pattern for a frame. I never thing about it from javafx but this should be simple to implement a builder of some sort that allow only one instance to be created at the same time.

Comment: Yes, Alex, i thought the same thing, haven't thought we could maybe create a sperate class and Spring it in? for a simple solution, I did add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [LazerBanana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4664558/lazerbanana) said, I would disable the button that opens the window, and I would enable it when you close it.

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
button.setDisable(true);
stage.setTitle(panelTitle);     
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); 
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stage.showAndWait();
// your logic here
button.setDisable(false);
```

Comment: This is the simple solution but if you are able to open the same window from multiple way, this is complicate to manage.

Comment: If you use a single `Stage` instance for your "popup window" (which should be easy to manage), you just need to do `button.disableProperty().bind(popupWindow.showingProperty());`. You would only need to call that once, when the button is created. That would be easy enough to manage for any controls that opened that window.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to creating a new one each time is to create one and just setup and show.

```
public class Stack extends Application {

    private final Stage popup = new Stage();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPrefWidth(400);
        root.setPrefHeight(200);

        Button button = new Button("ClickMePopup");

        root.setCenter(button);

        button.setOnAction(
                event -> {
                    if (!popup.isShowing()) {
                        // you dont set modality because after the stage is set to visible second time it will throw an exception.
                        // Again depends on what you need.
                        // popup.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

                        // this focuses the popup and main window is not clickable
                        // popup.initOwner(stage);

                        VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                        dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text("Some Dialog"));
                        Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 200);
                        popup.setScene(dialogScene);

                        // you can actually put all above into the method called initPopup() or whatever, do it once, and just show it here or just bind the property to the button.

                        popup.show();
                    }
                });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Stack");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Or disable the button when clicked, but if your popup is not driven by the button or can be opened from other places the first idea would be a bit better in my opinion. Depends on what you need.

Or just create your own class and Springify it.